# Rails Asset Pipeline - problems compiling jQuery UI assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2.3 and deploying to Heroku's Cedar Stack and I am having problems with my asset pipeline and compiling the jQuery UI files I need.

Specifically the problem manifests itself in two separate issues that I think are related:

1) in development my dropdown buttons do not work, but in production they do

2) in development my datepicker and sliders do not work, and they also do not work in production. However, if I call the javascript (`<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`) at the top of my view, the datepicker and sliders work in development but not in production

I have tried [compiling the assets locally and also during slug compilation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar), but to no avail.

My application.js:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require jquery-ui
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require_tree .
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'jquery_datepicker'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

My config/environments/development.rb

```
 # Do not compress assets
 config.assets.compress = false

 # Expands the lines which load the assets
 config.assets.debug = true
```

My config/environments/production.rb:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

My layout application.html.erb:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show us your code.
But my guess is it may be a dom load issue.

Try putting your instantiation inside a `jQuery()` call;

Here's an example right from the twitter-bootstrap-rails;

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover();
  $(".tooltip").tooltip();
  $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

The same should go for any jquery UI autocompleters

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("input.search-autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: "/search"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing the name of 'jquery-ui' to like 'jquery-ui-1.0' and put that file of that name to your 'app/assets'. I'm guessing that the name clashed with something provided by the gems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately that didn't work. It is strange.  If I call the javascript using google's api at the top of my view `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` then the sliders and datepicker work fine. But I still don't know why it is not working correctly using the asset pipeline.

Comment: then just download that file and replace what is local on your machine. Probably your local version of jquery-ui is flawed.

Comment: Isn't jquery-ui getting pulled in through the jquery-rails gem though? Unless I am misunderstanding how that gem works.